# How to list all Google document from the Domain using Drive SDK?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I want to list all the document from google domain.I have tried the as per mention in google documentation :
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#examples

I have created service with as follow :

```
 HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
      .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
      .build();
  Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

  Files.List request = service.files().list();
```

When i am executing this request as follows :

```
 FileList files = request.execute();
```

I got only '`userEmail`' (Provided while creating service) files.

How i can get all domain google drive files ?? i have used super admin but i couldn't get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get all files in your Google Apps domain you would need to:

1. Setup [domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) with your Service Account and Apps.
2. Use the Directory API [users.list()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) API call to determine all users in the Google Apps domain.
3. As each user, call [files.list(q='"me" in owners')](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) to get a list of all files the user owns.

The combined results of all these calls would be all files in your Google Apps domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't :) because Google Drive file ownership logic is user-centric.

You can only list files that are in the "My Drive" of the user used to call APIs.