# Can I restrict a Google Drives list() request to files owned within my domain?

Tags: google-drive-api

I've written a script to seize ownership of files shared to a central account.

It works, but there are tens of thousands of files that are shared with this central account from outside our domain.

I can't seize these files ... that's OK, and I understand that.

However, my script must trawl through these every day!

Is there some way to structure my query string so the call to list() returns only files owned by someone in my domain?

Currently my query string is: `'not "central.account@mydomain.com" in owners'`

This gets all of the files shared with central.account@mydomain.com that haven't already been seized.

I'd like something like this: `'not "central.account@mydomain.com" in owners and "%@mydomain.%" in owners'`

Notes:

We have mydomain.com, mydomain.com.au, mydomain.co.uk ... hence the second wildcards.

For the wildcards I've tried "%", "_" and "*".

Comment: I haven't tried it but use **`corpora`** set to **`domain`** to get the "Files shared to the user's domain." Also try using a service account and follow the suggested action in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29492145/5995040).

Comment: Thanks @MrRebot corpora looks like it'll do the job, but results are interesting ... it returns a few (132 rather than 30k+) files owned outside of the domain, and returns files from within the domain that don't come up without the corpora parameter. Further investigation required! As to the service account, yes, we're already doing that (to enable us to impersonate the user while changing ownership).